# ¿Puedo cambiar la contraseña para identificarme en OpenXava (sin XavaPro)?

Tags: java, seguridad, openxava

Cuando ejecuto mi aplicación OpenXava la única manera de identificarme es usando 'admin' como usuario y 'admin' como contraseña:

[image: Página de bienvenida de OpenXava]

¿Puedo definir una contraseña diferente para el usuario admin? Usando el OpenXava básico, sin  XavaPro.

Answer (score 0):

En la carpeta 'properties' dentro de tu proyecto puedes encontrar un archivo llamado naviox-users.properties, con este contenido:

```
# In plain OpenXava the users are added here in the form user=password
# If you want full management of users, roles and modules stored in database, 
#   get XavaPro from here: http://www.openxava.org/xavapro

admin=admin
```

Edítalo y cambia admin=admin por admin=tucontraseña. Has de reiniciar tu aplicación para que surta efecto.

Para aprender más sobre seguridad y gestión de usuarios con OpenXava mira:
https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/security_es.html